# How can I put images in a var memory_array memory game?

Tags: javascript, html, image, css, memory

I'm making a memory game in Javascript but I want to put images in my code instead of numbers or letters.

This is my code:

```
var memory_array =  [0,'0','1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4','5','5'];
```

How can I change this to images?

I tried this options like:

```
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'imgArray/img/parra.jpg'

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'imgArray/img/adidas.jpg';
```

But so far, nothing works. 
I'm stuck can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have `img` elements in the array (not just their URLs), you can make yourself a function to create them:

```
function createImage(src) {
    var img = document.createElement('img'); // Or `= new Image();`, doesn't matter
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

And then use it in an array initializer:

```
var memory_array = [
    createImage("/path/to/an/image.jpg"),
    createImage("/path/to/another/image.jpg"),
    createImage("/path/to/a/third/image.jpg")
];
```